# How to find a mongo document with TypeOrm using the ObjectId

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using MongoDB and TypeOrm and I was wondering how one can find a document using the mongo id

```
_id: ObjectId("6419695f7a702e2211d88c07"),
...
```

Now, TypeOrm has a utility or class for almost everything, but what I can't figure out is how to query using `_id`

I've seen some post which state that you have to import `ObjectID` from `mongodb`

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb'
```

So you can do

```
 this.repository.find({
  where: { _id: ObjectID("234234232342342")}
});
```

But why should I install a whole database if I only want the ObjectID utility. Doesn't make any sense. Also, when I try to do `npm install mongodb` it completely fails, but that is an other problem for an other post :)

So my question is, can TypeORM help me out here, or do I really have to install `mongodb`?

Comment: Did you have a look at the options presented here `https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3964`?

Comment: You can try using `bson` package instead of `mongodb`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson

Comment: try to instead of where use $where, if it didnt help, then just pass a string without ObjectID `from import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb'`

Comment: The only thing that worked for me is the bson library. Thanks a lot!